# C* algebras with no nilpotent elements are commutative

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am currently following my first course in operator algebras and I heard my teacher say that a C* algebra is commutative if and only its only nilpotent element is zero.

The first implication is obvious but I really cant figure out the second one.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Blackadar's "operator algebras" P II.6.4.14 for "noncommutative algebra implies $x^2=0$ for some $x\neq 0$". Don't know about the converse.

Comment: In the book of Dixmier J.: $C^\ast$-Algebras, the implication "If the only nilpotent element of a $C^\ast$ algebra $A$ is $0$ then $A$ is commutative" is stated as problem (2.12.21, page 68) with instructions.

Comment: It is proved in my answer to the following on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435659/for-what-kind-of-c-algebras-does-the-inequality-fracabba2-leq-frac
The proof uses basic representation theory for $C^\ast$-algebras and in particular Kadison's transitivity theorem.